# Tensorflow: NotImplementedError: The reduce() transformation does not currently support nested datasets as inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In Tensorflow 1.12 the `tf.data.Dataset.reduce()` and `tf.data.Dataset.window()` methods are introduced.

From the release notes:

- "New `tf.data.Dataset.reduce()` API allows users to reduce a finite dataset to a single element using a user-provided reduce function."
- "New `tf.data.Dataset.window()` API allows users to create finite windows of input dataset; when combined with the `tf.data.Dataset.reduce()` API, this allows users to implement customized batching."

However how to use these functions?

```
def reduce_func(old_state, input_element):
    pdb.set_trace()
    return new_state

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(frame_generator, (tf.string, tf.string))
dataset = dataset.window(2).reduce(np.int64(0), reduce_func)
```

This gives a NotImplementedError:

> NotImplementedError: The reduce() transformation does not currently
>   support nested datasets as inputs.

I use tensorflow version '1.12.0-rc1'

EDIT:
From https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/sliding_window_batch

*THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED.* It will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use `tf.data.Dataset.window(size=window_size, shift=window_shift, stride=window_stride).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(window.size))`

But how to use this if the dataset is generated with

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(frame_generator, (tf.string, tf.string))
```

So each item in the dataset contains two elements. Then there is a TypeError:

> TypeError: () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

EDIT: 
Solved by using zip

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(frame_generator, (tf.string, tf.string))
window_size = 2
dataset = dataset.window(window_size).flat_map(lambda x,y: tf.data.Dataset.zip((x,y)).batch(window_size))
dataset = dataset.map(self.parse_function)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you call the `.reduce()` function it's applying to the outer dataset.
The dataset after calling `.window` is now a dataset where each element is itself a dataset.
What you want to do is to use reduce on those individual datasets created by window.
You can do this using map, and then mapping each of the inner datasets to a reduce.

```py
def reduce_func(old_state, input_element):
    pdb.set_trace()
    return new_state

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(frame_generator, (tf.string, tf.string))
dataset = dataset.window(2).map(lambda ds: ds.reduce(np.int64(0), reduce_func))
```